# Google Cloud Data Fusion variable in S3 path

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I have an S3 source in my pipeline. I would like to fetch the CSV file including today's date in the filename. Is it possible to somehow include the date in the path? Let's say the path is:

```
s3a://products-data/products_20210204.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical start time macro function in the name of the s3 file as s3a://products-data/products_**${logicalStartTime(yyyyMMdd)}**.csv. At runtime this will resolve to the today's date.

For more information about logical start time macro, please checkout the article here - https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KB/pages/269910059/Add+processed+date+to+all+records+in+the+destination